# How do I migrate db.child() from Firebase 2?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have several calls to db.child() in my app where I was using Firebase 2.4.2 as a signaling server.

```
this.channels = {
  announce: this.db.child('announce'),
  signal: this.db.child('messages').child(this.id)
};

this.channels.signal.on('child_added', this.onSignal.bind(self));
this.channels.announce.on('child_added', this.onAnnounce.bind(self));
```

Once signaling is finished, I would send messages back and forth like so:

`this.db.child('messages').child( id ).push(msg);`

I have to migrate to the latest Firebase. I have access to the database in my app, but `this.db.child is not a function`. How do I migrate these calls to Firebase 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Referrence.child()` and `Snapshot.child()` are still existing methods in the 3.x and 4.x versions of the Firebase Database API.

Based on that, a very quick guess is that you need:

```
this.db.ref('messages').child( id )
```

But it's impossible to be certain, because your code doesn't show how `this.db` gets initialized.

For the most direct help in porting your code from 2.x to 3.x, see this guide: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Comment: In Firebase 2.4.2

`this.db = new Firebase(this.url);`

Comment: OK, so that becomes `this.db = firebase.database().ref();`. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, getting a reference to the root is now indeed done with `firebase.database().ref()`. Follow along with the guide and you should be able to get most things working. If you get stuck along the way, post a question with the [minimal **complete** code of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll take a look.